# Migrating from fusebox ColdFusion to PHP

Tags: php, zend-framework, coldfusion, migration, fusebox

I am currently working on converting a ColdFusion website, using Fusebox framework, to PHP. The site contains like 20,000 lines of ColdFusion code. My dilemma is, should I switch to Fusebox-PHP (as it will be easier to migrate the project layout) or a robust and popular framework like Symfony or Zend.

**Can anyone suggest a few points in favor or against the three options?**

1. migrate to Fusebox-PHP
2. migrate to Zend
3. migrate to Symfony

Comment: Does the migration _have_ to be to PHP? If this is a cost/licensing issue, there are FLOS alternatives to ColdFusion - migrating from ColdFusion+Fusebox -> [Railo](http://www.getrailo.org)+Fusebox will be _much_ easier...

Comment: If it does need to be to PHP, you will need to state which version of Fusebox is used, since I'm not sure if the PHP version was updated to the same level as the CF version, which affects how simple such a migration might be.

Comment: Yes,The migration needs to be to PHP only. The Fusebox version used 4.0.5

Comment: Yeah and there is no cost/licensing issue..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fusebox has been abandoned for a variety of issues (legal issues amongst them iirc). As long as you are rewriting it into PHP you might as well switch to a more current framework. Sure, you will have to learn how to do the same things a new way, but on the bright side you will have gained experience with a popular framework!

Ultimately Fusebox is dead and it would be unwise to use it (unless you were doing something turn-key like just migrating to Railo)

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is that Fusebox is an old framework that is not only not that popular with ColdFusion any more, but never really took off in the PHP world.

I would either find a new framework or do without the framework depending on the complexity of the site, there are many good PHP frameworks out there.

Looks like the last release for PHP was 7 years ago in 2005